# error message error kind on crytall report using vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I try to load the crystal report using a parameter, the code is as below

```
    Dim FrCr As New FrCr_Surat_jalan
    Dim kDf As Integer
    kDf = CInt(TxtFaktur.Text)
    FrCr.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{TDetail_Transaksi.kode_faktur} = '" & kDf & "'"
    FrCr.Show()
```

I get error as "number is required here "
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try like this ?

```
ReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{TDetail_Transaksi.kode_faktur} = '" & format(kDf) & "'"
```